# How to add border color to react virtualized table column (header and body together)?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a react virtualized table. Im trying to add a border color to the whole `description` column, like image below.

[image]

I've tried this : `style= {{ borderColor: "red"}}` in `<Column`, but seems like not working. How can I achieve this?

sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cray-7wn98r?file=/src/App.js